# how to use the facet_wrap(~list) with a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-analysis, facet-wrap

I have data on which I am performing an EDA.
One of the columns contains a list of characters.
I want to use `facet_wrap` with each unique value of the list instead of the whole list.

How can I do that?

Exp:

```
heights    diet
14.3       cw,ce,la
12.3       cw
11.2       ap, la
10.0       lp
12.3       ce,cw
```

I want to do different plots with each value of diet separately.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use `facet_wrap` for each value of `diet`? What are the x and y variables for the subplots?

Comment: @Aziz Yes, on each element of diet. My x will be heights and y another var, say z. And I want to group them with diet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- structure(list(heights = c(14.3, 12.3, 11.2, 10, 12.3), diet = c("cw,ce,la", 
"cw", "ap, la", "lp", "ce,cw"), z = c(-0.940250088024965, -0.916085008989365, 
0.346802165714023, 0.416379800831458, -0.284455862566136)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

#Separate cols, we place 3 because the largest number of diets is 3 in first row
#If you have more you would have to expand such quantity
df2 <- separate(df,col = diet,into = paste0('diet',1:3),sep = ',')
#Pivot
df3 <- pivot_longer(df2,cols = names(df2)[which(grepl('diet',names(df2)))])
#Prepare plot
df4 <- df3 %>% mutate(value=trimws(value)) %>% filter(!is.na(value))
#Plot
ggplot(df4,aes(x=heights,y=z))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(.~value)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked with my current dataset excately as I wanted it. Thank you SO much.

Comment: @thatsilentwatcher Great!! If you feel comfortable with this answer you could accept it by ticking it in the left side of this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're looking for to split the `diet` values in that column before plotting / faceting?
Then [`tidyr::separate_rows`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/separate_rows) might be a solution to your problem.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(diet, sep = ',') %>%
  ggplot() + ...
```

This will split the `diet` column at the provided separator into multiple rows while duplicating all other column values into each such generated row.